# When Int overflow cause IOS app crash, how can I remark it

Tags: ios, swift

My app have to use `int` to do some multiplication, it is easy to meet two fairly big numbers' multiplication.

Of course it will crash. And how can I remark some bool value. Just like every time before we'll quit the app, we `saveData` in the `AppDelegate.swift`'s function:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result of an integer arithmetic operation (+, -, *, /, ...)
overflows, the application terminates immediately. There is *no way* to
catch this situation or to get notified e.g. to save data.
There is no Swift error or `NSException` thrown which you could catch.
The same would happen for other runtime errors like accessing
an array element outside of the valid bounds, or unwrapping an
optional which is `nil`.

This means that you have to check beforehand if the integer arithmetic
operation can be executed. Alternatively – depending on your needs –
you can

- use the "Overflow operators" `&+`, `&-` and `&*` instead,
  which *truncate* the result instead of triggering an error,
  similar as in (Objective-)C.
- use [`addingReportingOverflow()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2885260-addingreportingoverflow) and similar methods which *“return the sum of this value and the given value, along with a Boolean value indicating whether overflow occurred in the operation.”*

Comment: it seems &+,&* can handle something like [Int.max*Int.max], So if there is no int-overflow the result is nothing different from using +,* , right?

Comment: @Microos: If the operation  does not overflow then the result of `&+` is identical to the result of `+`.

Comment: @ Martin R thank you! I will do some trials on it, that's really help me a lot

Comment: How do you accomplish "... you have to check beforehand if the integer arithmetic operation can be executed."? And &+ allows overflow rather than truncating

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: I meant “overflow” in the sense of “the result exceeds the available range and the program terminates immediately”, and “truncate” in the sense of “the result is truncated to the number of available bits”. – I have added another option which allows you to compute the sum *and* test for overflow in a single operation.

Comment: Thanks - and I misunderstood "truncate" to mean "limit to the maximum value" rather than live with the available bits.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer `NSInteger` over `Int`.

Use `NSInteger` when you don't know what kind of processor architecture your code might run on, so you may for some reason want the largest possible int type, which on `32` bit systems is just an int, while on a `64`-bit system it's a `long`.

stick with using `NSInteger` instead of int/long unless you specifically require them.

`NSInteger/NSUInteger` are defined as `*dynamic typedef *s` to one of these types, and they are defined like this:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thank you for coming and help me, but those data sometime is bigger than Int64.max, so I this is not able for me to handle then :(